# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setEscapeMessageFlag() on boolean

Tags: php, magento-2.1, controllers, customer-account, edit

I encountered this error unexpectedly. How can I find the solution to solve it?
This is where error occured

```
$resultPage->getLayout()->getBlock('messages')->setEscapeMessageFlag(true);
```

---

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function
>   setEscapeMessageFlag() on boolean in
>   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/Edit.php:83\n
>                Stack trace:\n
>
> #0 /var/www/html/magento2/var/generation/Magento/Customer/Controller/Account/Edit/Interceptor.php(24):
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Edit->execute()\n
>
> #1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(102):
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Edit\Interceptor->execute()\n
>
> #2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(74):
>   Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))\n
>
> #3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(70):
>   Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\Edit\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch',
>   Array)\n
>
> #4
>   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Chain/Chain.php(63):
>   Magento\Framework\Interception\Chain\Chain->invokeNext('Magento\\Custome...',
>   'dispatch', Object(Magento\Customer\Con in
>   /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Account/Edit.php
>   on line 83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known Magento bug:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4127

Basically if the page lacks page.messages block, it will cause Magento 2 fail with critical error message (dev mode) or white screen of death (production mode). Usually it happens when your layout contains something like this:

```
<referenceBlock name="page.messages" remove="true"/>
```

Removing message block is not a good practice anyway, so if you absolutely need to do it, just display empty template file instead.